# How to remove high frequncies having fft?

Tags: fourier-analysis, matlab

What are the units of measure of `FFT` elements?

Can I just set higher elements to zero to filter out higher frequencies? It looks like no.

```
>> x=0:0.1:10;
>> y=sin(x);
>> f=fft(y);
>> plot(real(f))
```

gives

[image]

which shows, that `FFT` contains not one peak for clear sinusoid.

If I set to zero upper half of `FFT`

```
>> f2=f;
>> f2(1,50:end)=0;
>> y2=ifft(f2);
>> plot(x,y,'-',x,y2,'x')
```

I get

[image]

the same sinusoid with lesser amplitude.

My questions are:

1) what are additional peaks in `FFT` for pure sinusoid?

2) aren't they relate with moire?

3) how to clear unneeded frequencies from `FFT` by zeroing elements?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/409319

Answer (score 2):

You don't have an integral number of waves in your function, so there is a jump discontinuity at the end of the interval.  This makes lots of high frequency content.  Try choosing a wavelength that fits evenly in your interval.
Look at the documentation for how the frequencies are arranged in $f$.  In [Numerical Recipes](http://nr.com/) there is a good discussion of what they claim is the practical standard-positive frequencies increase from zero to max through the first half of the fft array, then the negative frequencies come from max down to zero.  So when you zeroed out the last half of the array you removed all the negative frequencies.

Comment: Your link looks broken

Comment: P.S. So how to zero only high frequencies?

Comment: @SuzanCioc:  You would zero out the middle half of the array, if that is the way your software stores it.  Your big spikes are at low frequencies in this model.

Comment: finally I understood your point about negative frequencies: first `DFT` element is zero frequency, subsequent ones are positive frequencies, second half contains negative frequencies (in negative order). But your point about discontinuity seems to me as being wrong. Can you strengthen it please?

Comment: @SuzanCioc:  Your sine wave starts at $\sin 0=0$ and ends at $\sin 10 \approx -0.544$  When you make it a periodic function, there is a jump from $-0.544$ to $0$ at every multiple of $10$ in $x$.  That makes very high frequency content.

Comment: But where is it? High frequencies are located in the center of DFT spectrum, but I have zero there. Look at the first plot: no peaks at the center!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** 1: By default the fft function in MATLAB starts indexing at 0. In order to get an accurate plot, use the [fftshift](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fftshift.html) function.

**Hint** 2: The deltas of the Fourier transform of a sinusoid come in complex conjugate pairs.